# What's causing this object to show diamond artifacts in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

On render and in the preview shown, a lot of faces are bisected, with half shaded differently. It only happens in Cycles. It shows up
even if there is no material. I tried redoing the UV map. I recalculated the normals. I got rid of the environment and it's still there. There aren't any modifiers. I selected all the vertices and did a Merge-by-Distance, which didn't merge anything.

Wha....?

In case it's relevant, this is Blender 2.81a on Ubuntu 18.04 with an nVidia Geforce GTX 1060.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, I dropped back to 2.81a after upgrading to 2.82 and having crashes and other problems. Maybe also relevant.

Comment: Also, I'm using a recent video driver. I have several others available on the drive to try. I'll see if that helps.

Comment: I checked and found that it's the shadows from the light. Also after scaling down the object to 0.1 the pattern disappeared. I do not know why though, thus i didn't write it as answer.

Comment: @Xylvier It doesn't make sense that they would be shadows. The shading has nothing to do with any contours and doesn't look at all like shadows. However, it's true - if you scale it down, it goes away. Thanks for that fix.